# How can I show that $\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\to N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Given that $X\in Po(\lambda)$ how can I show that $\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\to N(0,1)$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ ?

I really have no clue on this... All i know is that by definition, convergence in distribution is defined as $X_{n}\to X$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: That is NOT how convergence in distribution is defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way: First imagine $\lambda$ approaching $\infty$ by going along a set of integer multiples of some positive number $\lambda_0$, thus: $\lambda_0,2\lambda_0,3\lambda_0,\ldots$.  Then recall that the sum of $n$ independent random variables each distributed as $\operatorname{Po}(\lambda_0)$ is distributed as $\operatorname{Po}(n\lambda_0)$.  Since it's a sum of independent random variables with the same distribution, the central limit theorem applies, so you can say $$\dfrac{\text{that sum minus its expected value}}{\text{its standard deviation}}$$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$.  Then observe that that same limit appies for EVERY value of $\lambda_0$, so you can just say that's the limit in distribution as $\lambda\to\infty$.  Then recall that the expected value and standard deviation for the Poisson distribution with parameter $\alpha$ are respectively $\alpha$ and $\sqrt{\alpha}$.